# Efficiently read in 2nd column of CSV into List of Lists in Python 3

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, array, file

I created a function to read in arbitrary numbers of .csv files, their 2nd column only, into a list of lists (or if there is a more efficient data structure, then that). I want it to be efficient and scalable/customizable. 
Is there anything in it that can be tweaked and improved?

```
import os
FILE_NAMES=["DOCS/1.csv","DOCS/2.csv"]

def FUNC_READ_FILES(file_names): 
    nr_files=len(file_names)
    filedata=[[] for x in range(nr_files)] # efficient list of lists

    for i in range(nr_files):   # read in the files
        if(os.path.isfile(file_names[i])):
           with open(file_names[i],'r') as f:
              filedata[i]=f.readlines()
        else:
             print("ERROR: FILES ARE MISSING!!!!") 
             exit() 

    for i in range(nr_files):  # iterate through the files and only keep the 2nd column, remove \n if it's end of line
       for k in range(len(filedata[0])):
        filedata[i][k]=filedata[i][k].strip().split(',')[1]

    return (filedata)

FUNC_READ_FILES(FILE_NAMES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are in python 3.x, I'd suggest looking into asyncio for the CPU intensive file I/O operations.

---

In your code, you are first reading each and every line from the csv into memory, and then processing that data. This is highly inefficient. Process those lines as soon as you get to them, so that your memory overhead is minimal.

---

Instead of iterating over the indices of the list of files, iterate over the files themselves:

```
filedata = []
for file_name in file_names:
    if(os.path.isfile(file_name)):
        with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            filedata.append([row[1] for row in reader])
    else:
         print("ERROR: FILES ARE MISSING!!!!") 
         exit()
```

will replace the following

```
for i in range(nr_files):   # read in the files
    if(os.path.isfile(file_names[i])):
       with open(file_names[i],'r') as f:
          filedata[i]=f.readlines()
    else:
         print("ERROR: FILES ARE MISSING!!!!") 
         exit() 
for i in range(nr_files):  # iterate through the files and only keep the 2nd column, remove \n if it's end of line
   for k in range(len(filedata[0])):
    filedata[i][k]=filedata[i][k].strip().split(',')[1]
```

Comment: "In your code, you are first reading each and every line from the csv into memory, and then processing that data."  -> That is because the readlines() function reads in the entire file. I can't access the lines to go over line by line and isolate the 2nd column if the function reads in the entire file at once. So I just go over it again, but this time line by line to do the work. If you have a solution for that, please edit your answer and include it.

Comment: @douglas780 Python has an inbuilt module: `csv` for parsing csv files: http://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/csv

Comment: I tested your suggestions but none of them work (I'm using Python 3.5.x), the `filedata=[[] * nr_files]` simply doesn't work it gives out `list assignment index out of range` error, probably not a good way to declare list of lists in python3. The other suggestion also doesn't work for `nr_files` since that `int` object is not iterable, must use `range()` there, and the same issue for the other for loop as well, can't take away the pointer variable from there. I'll look into the `csv` module, but the other suggestions don't work.

Comment: @douglas780 Sorry about the `filedata=[[] * nr_files]` comment. I have removed that. It works as `filedata=[[]] * nr_files`, but creates duplicates. Editing any one of the sublist modifies all of them. I have removed that; and placed the rewritten piece of code using `csv` module.

Answer (score 1):

## General remarks

### pep 8

for your names and code style, try to follow [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

- `lower_case` for variable and function names
- spaces around operators

### main guard

put the calling of your functions after a `if __name__ == '__main__':`, so you can load the script from somewhere else without it executing the code immediately

### looping

Don't loop over indices. Code like `for i in range(nr_files):`  is a lot cleaner using `enumerate`: `for i, filename in enumerate(file_names)`.

I suggest you check out the excellent 'Looping like a Pro' talk by David Baumgold

### functions

Instead of having 1 function to load the files, loop over them and pick the correct element, seasiest would be to split if into different functions:

1. takes the list of files, and passes them on one by one to the parse
2. parse a single file

### Generators

The most pythonic an efficient approach to do this would be to use generators, `pathlib.Path` and the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module

## My solution

### parse one file

This function takes a filehandle, and parses the requested element from the line

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path


def parse_file(filehandle, field_name):
    kwargs = {  # https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params
        'delimiter': ',',
        'skipinitialspace': True,
        # ...
    }
#     field_name = b  # or the column name 
    reader = csv.DictReader(filehandle, **kwargs)  # or csv.reader if there is no header, and it might be faster
    for line in reader:
        yield line[field_name]
```

This can be easily tested like this:

```
from io import StringIO
csv_str = '''a, b, c
0, 1, 2
3, 4, 5'''
with StringIO(csv_str, newline='') as file:
    print(list(parse_file(file, 'b')))
```

> ```
> ['1', '4']
> ```

### parse multiple file

```
def parse_files(files):
    for file in files:
        try:
            with filename.open('r', newline='', ) as csv_file:
                yield list(parse_file(csv_file))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("ERROR: FILES ARE MISSING!!!!")
            raise
```

Now we have a good method to parse the information, we just need to call it with the subsequent files

### main

```
def main(files):
    results = list(parse_files(files))
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':

    files= [Path("DOCS/1.csv"),Path("DOCS/2.csv")]
    main(files)
```